# How to speed up a for loop in R for a nested matrix matching and colSums

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have an apparently simple problem for which I require a faster R implementation than the one I developed

I initialize random seed and dimensions for this example:

```
set.seed(1)
d1<-400
d2<-20000
d3<-50
```

I have a matrix X, with dimensions *d1* x *d2*:

```
X<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(d1*d2),nrow=d1,ncol=d2))
rownames(X)<-paste0("row",1:nrow(X))
colnames(X)<-paste0("col",1:ncol(X))
```

And a vector u with *d1* row indexes:

```
u<-sample(rownames(X),nrow(X),replace=TRUE)
```

I have also a matrix C with named rows and dimensions *d3* x *d2*:

```
C<-matrix(rnorm(d3*d2),nrow=d3,ncol=d2)
rownames(C)<-sample(rownames(X),nrow(C),replace=FALSE)
```

Now, with the following **very slow** loop I am filling the matrix C with the sums of matching X rows:

```
system.time(
    for(i in 1:nrow(C)){
        indexes<-which(u==rownames(C)[i])
        C[i,] <- colSums(X[indexes,])
    }
)
```

This operation takes approximately 11.5 seconds on my PC, but I am sure it could be sped up by avoiding the for loop. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the rationale behind `replace=TRUE` in `u` creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `matrixStats::colSums2` with the option to pass row indexes & move `rownames()` outside the loop (`X` need to be converted to matrix):

```
Xm <- as.matrix(X)
names_of_rows <- rownames(C)
system.time(for (i in 1:nrow(C)) {
  indexes <- which(u == names_of_rows[i])
  C[i, ] <-  matrixStats::colSums2(Xm, rows = indexes)
})
# 0.03 sek
```

Comment: All solutions so far have been beautiful, but this one is perfect. More than 100x speed up. Thank you minem, you have helped immensely.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `sapply` for looping.

```
system.time(
  C2 <- `dimnames<-`(t(sapply(match(rownames(C), u), function(x) 
    colSums(X[x, ]))), list(rownames(C), NULL))
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 20.06    0.03   20.14 

stopifnot(all.equal(C, C2))
```

Compared to

```
system.time(
  for(i in 1:nrow(C)){
    indexes <- which(u == rownames(C)[i])
    C[i, ] <- colSums(X[indexes, ])
  }
)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 20.76    0.69   28.30
```

At the moment, however, it is only a single measurement.

#### Update

Appears to run *slightly* faster...

```
Unit: seconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 forloop 20.44852 20.57730 21.67771 20.74106 21.01723 29.63220    10   a
  sapply 19.86707 20.17126 21.34529 20.50283 20.81254 29.73764    10   a
```

#### Update 2

But you may do it with `parallel::parSapply`.

```
system.time({
  library(parallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
  clusterExport(cl, c("C", "u", "X"))
  C3 <- parSapply(cl, match(rownames(C), u), function(x) colSums(X[x, ]))
  stopCluster(cl)
  C3 <- `dimnames<-`(t(C3), list(rownames(C), NULL))
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.81    3.16    9.82

stopifnot(all.equal(C, C3))
```

Now, my machine is as fast as yours with the `for`-loop :)

Comment: Thank you jay.sf, it is an interesting solution, but with margin of improvements. I am thinking of implementing this in C, but I would like to scout the community for R-pure solutions :-)

Comment: @FedericoGiorgi See update. For C you may want to look into [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Venturing a `data.table` solution here. If OP wants only a base R solution, I will delete this post:

```
library(data.table)
mtd_dt <- function() {
    setDT(dtX)[, u := as.integer(gsub("row","",u))]
    mX <- melt(dtX, id.var="u", variable.name="col")
    C2 <- data.table(rn=seq_len(nrow(C)), u=as.integer(gsub("row","",rownames(C))))
    dcast(mX[C2, on=.(u)][, sum(value), by=.(rn, col)], rn ~ col, value.var="V1")[,
        "NA" := NULL][,
            lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))]
}
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 14
  expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result                    memory                time    gc             
  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>                    <list>                <list>  <list>         
1 mtd0()        59.1s    59.1s    59.1s    59.1s    0.0169     447MB    24     1      59.1s <dbl [50 x 20,000]>       <Rprofmem [44,515 x ~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x 3~
2 mtd_dt()       2.7s     2.7s     2.7s     2.7s    0.370      309MB     4     1       2.7s <data.table [50 x 20,001~ <Rprofmem [88,029 x ~ <bch:t~ <tibble [1 x 3~
```

timing code:

```
mtd0 <- function() {
    for (i in 1:nrow(C)) {
        indexes <- which(u==rownames(C)[i])
        C[i, ] <- colSums(X[indexes, ])
    }
    C
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd_dt(), check=FALSE)
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0)
#d1 <- 10
#d2 <- 10
#d3 <- 5
d1<-400
d2<-20000
d3<-50

X <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(d1*d2),nrow=d1,ncol=d2))
rownames(X) <- paste0("row",1:nrow(X))
colnames(X) <- paste0("col",1:ncol(X))
dtX <- X

u <- sample(rownames(X),nrow(X),replace=TRUE)

C <- matrix(0,nrow=d3,ncol=d2)
rownames(C) <- sample(rownames(X),nrow(C),replace=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! A very interesting solution leveraging on the powerful data.table. Not the winner, just because the matrixStats::colSums2() solution is faster